# I'm trying to deploy my simple typescript app to firebase cloud functions. But I have got this error

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

```
Build failed: ...sing: idb@7.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-check-types@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: selenium-webdriver@4.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/auth-types@0.11.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.6.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/firestore-types@2.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-check-interop-types@0.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/messaging-interop-types@0.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/functions-types@0.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/installations-types@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/performance-types@0.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/remote-config-types@0.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/storage-types@0.6.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @grammyjs/types@2.8.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: chokidar@3.5.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: debug@3.2.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ignore-by-default@1.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: pstree.remy@1.1.8 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: semver@5.7.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: simple-update-notifier@1.0.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: touch@3.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: undefsafe@2.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: anymatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: fsevents@2.3.2 from lock file...
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-08-22T07_49_29_487Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        router(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

Comment: more details needed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not executed "npm install". After deployment you have to install your dependencies